# Background color fade out with no hover

Tags: css, webkit, transition

I'm trying to get a css background color to fade out right after the page loads without any user interaction. Can this be done?

Comment: `transition` in CSS. And jQuery to get the document load. Or JS. Like [this](http://jsbin.com/hucelifi/1)?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using CSS animations. There is a property animation-delay which can be set in seconds.

```
animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;
-o-animation-delay: 2s;
```

Here is a simple example of a background fading after 2 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/eKAf2/

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd have the background set in CSS. Then modify the document with jQuery. So I'd set the background color

CSS

```
body {
    background: #009dff;
}
```

Then set the background color that the page fades into, and add the transition

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").css("transition", "3s"); // Adding transition
   $("body").css("background", "#fff"); //Background color to fade into 
});
```

Plus [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/P7TDu/) a demo.

With pure JS you can use `onload` on the body and set up a function, then call it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you had an element eg: .elem

```
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Styles:

```
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
 }
```

You could have a css class eh .nobackground that set the background to transparent with a transition.

```
.nobackground {
  background: transparent !important;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

You could then apply this class to the element on page load with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".elem").addClass("nobackground");

});
```

Heres a [bin](http://jsbin.com/monal/3/). Hope this helps.